# swift request body empty

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, networking

I'm having issues sending a post request to my api.I set the App transport security to allow local Networking. the problem is that the request body is always empty

Here is my swift code

```
func createClient(client:Client) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3003/client_create") else {
        print("Could not create URL.")
        return
    }

        let requestLang: [String: Any] = ["nom_complet": client.nom_complet]
        let requestBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestLang)

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpBody = requestBody
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {

        data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            return
        }

        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            print(responseJSON)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
    }
```

Here is my node js code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mysql = require('mysql')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}) )
app.use(express.static('./public'))

function getConnection() {
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'expertDB'
    })
}

var publicDir = require('path').join(__dirname,'/public'); 
app.use(express.static(publicDir));



app.post('/client_create', (req,res) => {
    try{
    const nom_complet = req.body.nom_complet
    console.log("nom_complet: "+nom_complet)
    console.log("body "+req.body)
    const queryString = "INSERT INTO Client (nom_complet) VALUES (?)"
    const connection = getConnection()
    connection.query(queryString,[nom_complet],(err,results,fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("failed to connect to server")
            console.log(err)
            res.sendStatus(500)
            return 
        }
        console.log('inserted a new client with id: ',results.insertedId);
        res.end()
    })

}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
})
```

the req.body is returning empty and req.body. nom_complet is returning undefined
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: How di you know it's empty?

Comment: in my node js rest api when i get the request body i found it is empty

Comment: Check if `requestBody` is empty or not, but your request seems fine, so it's on your Node.js part...

Comment: I already checked the request body and it is empty

Comment: What. `let requestBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestLang)` returns nil? What is `client.nom_complet`?

Comment: no requestBody is not nil and client.nom_complet is a simple string having the value written in textfield and he is not also nil

Comment: Then, since there is nothing wrong with the Swift code, it might be on the Node.js one. Would you mind showing your code and how you check it’s body is empty?

Comment: I just posted it and when console.log is executed it displays the req.body is empty

Answer (score 0):

In my case that helped:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))
```

you can try removing the UTF8 string where u specify the application/json and leave only the application/json if that does not work immidiatley